# Creating dynamically objects from wall to wall

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How can I to generate cubes from left wall to right wall in Script dynamically in Unity?
I tried something like this:

```
cube.transform.position = new Vector3(Screen.width, Screen.height, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

The code you have now will just create a single cube in the corner of the screen. What you need is a for loop that starts at 0 and goes to Screen.Width. I don't remember the exact syntax for spawning a new object but something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Screen.Width; i +=sizeOfCube)
{
    Instantiate(cube, new vector3(i, 10, 0));
}
```

Comment: Instantiate(cube, new Vector3(i, 10, 0), Quaternion.identity);

Comment: But Screen.width get me width of screen in pixel and if my cube have width 1.0f, this script create me about 1200 cubes.

Comment: Then you need to use a larger cube. You can create an empty gamobject and attatch the script to it. Then you can have a "public GameObject cube" variable where you can attach a cube prefab in the inspector. That cube can be whatever size you want